# Flutter: how to access ScopeModel properties in child pages

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to understand ScopeModel in Flutter and need some help on how access  values from the model on a different page

My home page has a bottom navigation bar and when click just display the search page. I have wrap the widget tree with the ScopeModel and added the model.

The count is getting incremented but I am not sure how to access it from the search page

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScopeCounter sc;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     sc = new ScopeCounter();
  }
  final List<Widget> _children = [
   ..
    Search()
  ];
  var _currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModel(
        model:sc ,
          child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Center(child: Text("test")),
          ),
          drawer: JobsDrawer(),
          body: _children[_currentIndex],
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              onTap: onTabTapped, // new
              currentIndex: _currentIndex, // new
              items: [
                new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
                  title: new Text("search"),
                )
              ])),
    );
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
       sc.increment();         
      print(sc.counter1.count);
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

This my Model

```
class ScopeCounter extends Model {
   Counter counter1 = Counter();
    increment() {
    counter1.count += 1;
    }
}
class Counter {
  int count = 1;
}
```

Search page

```
class Search extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Form(
        ...

  }
}
```

I would like access the count from the "search" page.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to wrap your SearchPage's Widget (Scaffold in this case) with a ScopedModelDescendant Widget. This gives you access to your ScopedModel.

A great explanation can be found in the documentation: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

EDIT: Also your ScopedModel must be a parent of both: MyHomePage and Search.